# Is there an example on R of a sequence converging to multiple points?

Tags: general-topology

In section 17 of Topology by Munkres, he gives an example of a sequence converging to multiple points, then gives definitions for the T1 axiom and Hausdorff space to avoid those situations.

Is there a less general example for a topological space for $\mathbb R $ that also converges to multiple points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the [indiscrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology): the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$.  Then every sequence converges to every point.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the usual topology, since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff so every sequence converges to at most one point . . .

If you're just looking for a nice concrete example, though, in the two-element set $\{a, b\}$ with the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset, \{a, b\}\}$, the sequence $a, a, a, a, a, a, a, .  .  .$ converges to both $a$ and $b$; do you see why? *More generally, in an indiscrete space, every sequence converges to every point.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider on $\Bbb R$ the topology:

$$\mathcal T = \{\emptyset, \Bbb R\} \cup \{(a, \infty): a \in \Bbb R\}$$

Verify that $\frac1n \to x$, for all $x \le 0$ (but $\frac1n$ does not converge to any $x > 0$)